# Relation between SNR and fading channel coefficients?

Tags: digital-communications, signal-power, fading-channel

I am trying to understand the following thing:

Does the average signal to noise ratio (SNR) depends on fading channel coefficients ?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "fading channel coefficients"? How is your SNR defined? Writing them down with mathematical expressions would help us.

Comment: Fading channel coefficients: complex channel gains

Answer (score 1):

In the literature, the SNR definition may alter due to its use. In fading channel, the performance of the receiver depends upon the **received** signal power to **thermal** noise power Let complex message signal $x(t)$ with power $P$ is transmitted over a fading channel with complex channel gain $h$. The received signal at the receiver can be written as $$y(t) = hx(t) + n_w(t),$$  where $n_w(t)$ is the complex additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN) with power spectral density $N_o$. ***Actually the power of thermal noise (AWGN) is infinite theoretically!!!*** After matched filtering and sampling at the receiver, the $k$-th sampling can be written as
$$y_k = h x_k +n_k$$
the power of the *complex* noise **per sample** ($n_k$) becomes $N_o\times 1/T$ and $T$ is the symbol period. Similarly, the power of $x_k$ becomes $P$. Therefore the **instantaneous** received SNR can be written as
$$ \gamma = |h|^2\frac{PT}{N_o} = |h|^2 \frac{E_s}{N_o}$$
where $E_s$ is the energy per symbol. Some of the studies defines the **average SNR as** $\bar{\gamma}= Es/N_o$ and some studies assumes that
$$ \bar{\gamma} = \mathbb{E} [\gamma] = \Omega \frac{E_s}{N_o}$$ where $\Omega = \mathbb{E} [|h|^2]$.

Sometimes defining received SNR is not useful and trivial(for spatial modulation, space shift keying, and MIMO techniques) since there are multiple receive antennas consequently multiple SNR values. Therefore, directly using $\bar{\gamma} = E_s/N_o$ is simply a better option.